# Why does local simpleDateFormat cause bug

Tags: java, findbugs, simpledateformat

I've just started using findbugs.
I had a static simpleDateFormat that I was using in general, and findbugs flagged that as a bug. OK, I agree, after looking at the references on simpleDateFormat.  But, I continue to get the static java.text.DateFormat bug on the following lines

1) final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd yyyy" );
2) final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

I am using eclipse, and it appears to me that the bugs that were flagged initially are still showing up even though the code has been modified.

I have another "fixed bug" that still shows up as a bug.  I implemented equals without overriding hashCode.  Now, I've added the hashCode method, but continue to recieve a bug that says that when equals is overridden then hashCode has to be overridden also.

Also, some of the initial bugs now show up on comment lines, suggesting again, that the original bugs / locations are being reported.

How can I clear the "bugs" in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

FindBugs works from compiled class files. Clean, then build your project and run FindBugs on it again.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) final SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd yyyy" );
>   2) final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

I just got the same problem last night heh. If you use either of these while multi threaded it will crash. SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe. So create them every time you use them or synchronized them (which could slow down your multi threaded code.)

If you go into FindBugs perspective mode you can see the details on why something is a bug and sometimes has helpful links or work arounds.

> I am using eclipse, and it appears to me that the bugs that were
>   flagged initially are still showing up even though the code has been
>   modified.

Rerun findbugs again. Every change you do you kind of need to rerun FindBugs.

> How can I clear the "bugs" in Eclipse?

Right click your project -> Find bugs -> Clear Bug Markers.